# Specify registry as argument in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I would like to do the following, using [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg):

```
ARG registry
FROM $registry/pipenv
...
```

But, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), `FROM`must be the first keyword in a valid `Dockerfile`.

How can I specify a registry from outside the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: Actually, the documentation says: ARG is the only instruction that may precede FROM in the Dockerfile. See Understand how ARG and FROM interact. Checking that section reveals a valid example mirroring what you put in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you posted, there is one line says:

> ARG is the only instruction that may precede FROM in the Dockerfile.

And then follows a section talking about "Understand how ARG and FROM interact
".